# Is it possible to write Python code in a Django field?

Tags: python, django, sympy

I'm beginning to use Django to create a site.
Following the tutorials, i created a little app that allow to create questions.

I would like to create maths questions with Sympy which use Python variables.
The presentation is not a problem because i'm using mathjax.

More precisely, i would like to be able to do something like that in a question/answer field :

```
a = random.randint(1,9)    
f = x**a
F = integrate(f,x)
print(fr'''$f:x\mapsto {f}.$''')
```

I think i would then be able to compare an answer with what i expect by a comparison with sympy.

Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Are you asking the user to enter code within a text field and then attempting to run that code? This is a huge security vulnerability.

Comment: No, i would like the user to enter a text that would then be put in a python variable and compared to an expected answer with sympy. For exemple, the user enter : x**3/3. And this will just return true or false after a comparison.

Comment: But i would like the question to be randomized and displayed in tex with mathjax, hence my whish to make python code in the question.